# How to declare array of pointers to the another array elements

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have an array.

`char tab[200];`

and then I want to create array which consists pointers to the previous array elements

```
char** t = new (char*)[LENGTH];
```

but i do get

```
C:\Users\Duke\Desktop\PJC3\main.cpp|37|error: array bound forbidden after parenthesized type-id|
```

How should I declare it ***DYNAMICALLY***?

`EDIT`: Is that correct pointing to corresponding elements of the `tab` array?

```
char** t = new char*[dlugoscTab];

for(int i = 0; i < dlugoscTab; i++){
   *(t + i*sizeof(char)) = (tab + i*sizeof(char));
}
```

Comment: Why the parentheses? Did you read the error message?

Comment: `std::vector<char*> t(LENGTH, nullptr);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it the way you're trying to, you need to just get rid of the parentheses:

```
char** t = new char*[LENGTH];
for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
  t[0] = &tab[i];
}
```

However, there doesn't seem to be much of a reason to use dynamic allocation here, so just use an array of `char*`:

```
char* t[LENGTH];
for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
  t[0] = &tab[i];
}
```

Or better yet, use a standard container like `std::array` or `std::vector`.

The assignment in your edit is incorrect:

```
*(t + i*sizeof(char)) = (tab + i*sizeof(char));
```

It *will* work in this case but only because `sizeof(char)` is 1. You should not be involving `sizeof` here. Adding 1 to a pointer does not move it 1 byte, but moves it to point to the next object of the type it is pointing at. You should be doing:

```
*(t + i) = (tab + i);
```

But as I've written in my examples above, this is exactly the much easier to understand:

```
t[i] = &tab[i];
```

Comment: Thank you! what about my edit? Is that correct? I would like to point to the elements of the other array.

Comment: @RobertKilar I edited my answer - it's incorrect. Get rid of `sizeof(char)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
char** t = new (char*)[LENGTH];
```

Should be:

```
char** t = new char*[LENGTH];
```

If you want every `i`th element in `t` to point to the `i`th element in `tab`, you can simply do this like so:

```
for(int i=0; i<LENGTH; i++ )
    t[i] = & tab[i];
```

Comment: @RobertKilar You don't need to add `sizeof(char)`, pointer arithmetic automatically factors in the size of the type. Furthermore, what you're doing is way more complicated than it needs to be. Just use `t[i] = &tab[i]`. This way it's clear what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
char (*t)[LENGTH] = new char(*)[LENGTH];
```

But it doesn't make much sense to allocate it with **new** because that just allocates one pointer, not an array.

Comment: @JSQuareD this declares and dynamically allocates a pointer to an array of LENGTH characters, which is incidentally not what OP wants.